# Manually set an Altair drop down value scale

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a chart of Washington, DC condo prices and I'd like one of the drop down options to be "Year built". This is my code so far:

```
dropdown = alt.binding_select (options=["Square Feet", "Year built", "Rooms"], name="Select a size variable:")

# Create a new selection that uses my dynamic query widget
selection = alt.selection(type="single", fields=['column'], bind=dropdown, init={'column':'Square Feet'})


alt.Chart(altdat, title='Washington, D.C. condos, by price').transform_fold(
    ["Square Feet", "Year built", "Rooms"],
    as_=['column', 'value']
).transform_filter(
    selection
).mark_circle().encode(
    x = alt.X('Longitude', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[altdat['Longitude'].min(), altdat['Longitude'].max()])),
    y = alt.Y("Latitude", scale=alt.Scale(domain=[altdat['Latitude'].min(), altdat['Latitude'].max()])),
    color=alt.Color('Price (city appraisal)', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redyellowgreen', reverse=True)),
    size="value:Q",
    tooltip=["WARD", "Square Feet", "Year built", "Rooms"]
).add_selection(selection
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=600
).interactive()
```

However, when I select the year as the drop down, the scale goes from 0 to 2000, making it ineffective. [Altair image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzKEC.png) How can I scale just the Year variable to be from 1800 to 2000? I still want the Square Feet to go from 0 to 2000. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want zero to not be included in scales by default you can set `scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)` (not 100% sure this is what you are asking and I can't test it because the data is not provided in the question).